# Docusign - Control download and print & Notification

Tags: docusignapi

I have researched enough and went through the API and could not find what is the right object to set to not to let users download / print documents once they finish signing. All the documents are submitted using envelopeAPI and controlling all the eventNotifications via api.

Would like to control the following also via API.

1. Not to send completed email to the recipient.
   Once the document is signed, the recipient receives an email as shown below.

   [image: Completed email received by the recipient]

   What is tried so far -- Tried to change the Email preference for Api user and User and did not see
   any difference in notification.
2. Disable download and print option for the recipient.

when the recipients finish signing they are redirected to a page as shown below.
If possible I would the recipients not be redirected to this. If not at least disable download/print
option.

[image: Save a copy of the document]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of law in most jurisdictions, people who sign using an electronic signature **must** have the ability to view/download/print the signed document.

That said, you can use an embedded signing ceremony. In that case, you control the emails.

Comment: That makes sense why I could not find any option to disable that.